# Kivy settings performance

Tags: raspberry-pi, kivy

We are using Kivy for a RPi based project.

We use the Kivy Settings mechanism for editing of data records. Our main problem is, that creating a new settings dialog (via add_json_panel) takes quite a long  time (several seconds).

Note: We cannot pre create the dialogs, because we dynamically modify the dialogs fields.

Is there a way to speed this up?
What are the correct Kivy providers (text, image, window) for a RPi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is probably just outright slow - unfortunately the Settings widget is inflexible, outdated, and not up to modern Kivy standards. We've been discussing how to deprecate and replace it, but haven't taken action yet.

Depending on what you're doing, it may be simpler (and potentially much faster) to implement your own settings management widgets.